# How to write verbatim in a LaTeX macro?

Tags: macros, verbatim

I have a large number of places where I want to write some short snippets in verbatim mode, specifically with spaces preserved, within running text (within a paragraph). I really would like to create a macro for that, but cannot get it to work. The `verbatim` environment is not suitable as it creates a new paragraph, but I found the `\Verb+...+` from the `fancyvrb` package that does what I want. But it does not work in a macro (i.e. `\newcommand{}`). When I use it in a macro, then the switch to monospaced font still works, but multiple spaces get collapsed into single ones, different from using it outside a macro. Why does it behave differently within a macro?

How can I achieve what I want, possibly with something different than `fancyvrb`?

Comment: you can not use verb commands in an argument or definition as the argument is already tokenised with standard meannings before verb is executed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you willing and able to compile your document with LuaLaTeX, or are you bound to pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Can you please add an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: @Mico I need PDF output, and I used pdfLaTeX for that purpose a lot, so I hesitate to change to a different TeX version.

Comment: @egreg What I need is like '... the output of this is "  #1.: -209,   3, 476" ...', or ' the prompt for a command looks like "EX: ".' The surrounding text needs to be set normally as part of one paragraph with the part within double quotes in monospaced with spaces preserved. Note here in HTML the multiple spaces are also collapsed so cannot be seen until you'd try to edit my comment. So I need a macro such that I can write ' the prompt for a command looks like \macro{EX: }.'.

Comment: @PeterRottengatter - LuaLaTeX creates pdf output as well.

Answer (score 1):

If it is about code snippets, I recommend

```
\usepackage{listings}   
...
\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{SOURCEFILE.py}   % e.g. for Python
```

Comment: The snippets are not in files, and it is not really feasible to put them into files. In addition, they are not usually programming language code.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a macro `\defineverbatimphrase` which takes a macro name and reads and tokenizes from the .tex-file an argument in verbatim-catcode-régime and defines the macro to be robust and to  deliver the verbatim-argument wrapped in `\scantokens{...}`.

You may wish to switch the category code of horizontal tab (`^^I`) to 12 before `\defineverbatimphrase` grabs the verbatim-argument—`+v`-argument-type does not do that for you.

With the macro for delivering things wrapped in `\scantokens` you may wish to have a local scope which is valid while `\scantokens` does its fake-writing-part and where `\newlinechar` is equal to `\endlinechar` and you may wish to append a percent-character which, when `\scantokens` does its reading-back-and-retokenizing-of-the-fake-file-part, is recognized as a comment-character so that the endline-character which does get appended when `\scantokens` processes the last "line" of the fake-file is behind that comment-character and thus not processed by TeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\foo[1]{#1}%

\DeclareRobustCommand\defineverbatimphrase[1]{%
  \begingroup\catcode`\^^I=12 \innerdefineverbphrase{#1}%
}%
\begingroup
\makeatletter \catcode`\Z=14 \catcode`\%=12
\foo{Z
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\innerdefineverbphrase{m+v}{Z
    \endgroup
    \@ifdefinable{#1}{Z
      \DeclareRobustCommand#1{\begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar\scantokens{\endgroup#2%}}Z
    }Z
  }Z
}%

\defineverbatimphrase\myMacroA{\verb|AB#%§$_^\relax|}
\defineverbatimphrase\myMacroB{%
\begin{verbatim}
AB#%§$_^\relax
\end{verbatim}}

\begin{document}

\noindent text \foo{\myMacroA} text

\noindent text\myMacroB text

\end{document}
```

[image]